# Does an exponential bound on a Lyapunov candidate imply asymptotic stability?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

If I have a Lyapunov candidate $V:[0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and I'm able to show that $$ V(t)\le k e^{-\eta t} V(0),\qquad \forall t\in[0,\infty) $$
can I conclude something about asymptotic\exponential stability?

I ask this question  because on the definitions I read that $\dot{V}$ must be always negative (but in zero) to conclude that.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krasovskii%E2%80%93LaSalle_principle

Comment: Well, obviously, if this holds and if $V\geqslant0$ everywhere, then $V(t)\to0$, no?